# Can't press Ctrl+V at the same time but all other commands work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

An issue suddenly happened with my Logitech G105 keyboard this morning. All other commands involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> work apart from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I've tried reinstalling drivers and nothing seems to work.

Another issue is that when I try to boot the computer up in safe mode, upon reaching the Windows repair screen the keyboard doesn't work at all.

I tried an older keyboard and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> worked perfectly fine on it.

Oddly enough setting one of my G keys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> seems to work, I'm just not actually able to press the two keys at the same time.

[image]

Comment: as you've tried another keyboard, you've eliminated everything else...keyboard is busted, might just be a soldering issue.  I'd also imagine that other Ctrl+# combo's are affected but they're aren't used.

Comment: Does the right `Ctrl` key work?

Comment: Ctrl+# Are working. I use them in my MMOs and they switch my tabs in firefox. using the right Ctrl+v doesn't work either

Comment: This question should be closed or deleted because it's a transient, non-repeatable issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently after trying a bunch of things, simply plugging it into a second computer then back into mine fixed it.